# std::result::Result panic to log

Tags: rust

I run some code in a separate thread:

```
    fn f1() -> Result<(), String> { Err("err1".to_string()) }
    fn f2() -> Result<(), String> { Err("err2".to_string()) }
    ::std::thread::spawn(move || {
      f1().expect("f1 failed");
      f2().expect("f2 failed");
    });
```

also I use [log crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/log/log/index.html) for logging.

As result I want `panic!` to call `error!` instead of `print!`.

I found the [panic hook](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.PanicInfo.html), but I do not like `unwrap` in such code:

```
panic::set_hook(Box::new(|panic_info| {
    error!("panic occured: {:?}", panic_info.payload().downcast_ref::<&str>().unwrap());
}));
```

and I am worried about:

> This will commonly, but not always, be a `&'static str` or `String`

but would not `downcast` always succeeded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This will commonly, but not always, be a `&'static str` or `String`

This means that a developer (of one the libraries you use) could potentially use another type. In this case, the call to `downcast_ref` would fail.

My advice is to handle the cases you know about and add a catch-all case with a default message.

Also you should also consider printing the location, as it is incredibly useful even in the absence of message.

All told:

```
use std::panic;
use std::ops::Deref;

panic::set_hook(Box::new(|panic_info| {
    let (filename, line) =
        panic_info.location().map(|loc| (loc.file(), loc.line()))
            .unwrap_or(("<unknown>", 0));

    let cause = panic_info.payload().downcast_ref::<String>().map(String::deref);

    let cause = cause.unwrap_or_else(||
        panic_info.payload().downcast_ref::<&str>().map(|s| *s)
            .unwrap_or("<cause unknown>")
    );

    error!("A panic occurred at {}:{}: {}", filename, line, cause);
}));
```

Let's unwrap it:

- first we fetch the filename and line from the location, providing defaults in case they are unknown,
- then we check whether the `payload` is a `String`, and if so dereference it,
- then, if not, we check if it is a `&str`, and if not provide a default,
- finally, we print all the accumulated information.